# Horizontal flow layout for each collection section

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview

I would like to create `UICollectionView` with horizontal scrolling which is not hard to achieve. Simply setting

```
let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
```

I am going to have horizontal scrolling. The problem is whenever I add few sections into this, the population of cells is going to be like from bellow screen from the left hand side. What I would like to get it is on the right hand side. Each section has cells in lines.

I can achieve this placing few collections inside `UITableViewCell`'s but it would not be efficient -> synchronizing scrolls for each collection going to be painful.

[Sections visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOU7u.png)

Any advices ? How would look the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` for this scenario ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You need to set collectionView in Tableviewcell. in collectionview set the horizontal scrolling and tableview vertical scrolling. for the reference https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/

Comment: "I can achieve this placing few collections inside UITableViewCell's but it would not be efficient -> synchronizing scrolls for each collection going to be painful."